# how to serialize multidimensional arrays and fetch its value in android

Tags: android, serialization, multidimensional-array

i have to serialize the following array in android

```
my_date = new String[][] {
            {"14","26"},
            {"12","16","24","27"},
            {"17"},
            {"8","13","18"},
            {"14"},
            {},
            {"29"},
            {"15","18"},
            {},
            {"2","3","6","8","23"},
            {"4","6","24"},
            {}
    };
```

Comment: serialize in which format? binary? xml?... to save where? on a file? SQLite?

Comment: i have to save this in shared preferences

Answer (score 0):

Just like any other object:

- write

  final ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
  objectOutputStream.writeObject(my_date);
  objectOutputStream.close();
- read

  final ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
  final Object object = objectInputStream.readObject();
  objectInputStream.close();
  return object;

Comment: what is the file here                    If it is possible then plz help me with whole code

Comment: This is pretty much all the code. The "file" is, of course, a standard File object.